# os.system() problems when called from Python cron job

Tags: python, macos, path, cron

I use `Anaconda` Python installation and I also have a Python script that works correctly when called from the shell using `python update_data.py`. Then I wrote a short `cron` job with [`Python-Crontab` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab). Then I started having these problems on Mac OS X El Capitan:

1. `os.system()` returns `256` when it shouldn't.
2. Python packages like `Pandas, numpy` do not work correctly.

Here's my `cron` script.

```
import os
from crontab import CronTab

tab = CronTab()
job_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'update_data.py')
python_path = "/Users/BJay/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/python "

cron_job = tab.new(command=python_path + job_path)
cron_job.minute.every(2)
tab.write()
print(tab.render())
```

I set the var `python_path` with the output from `which python`. I did not provide information about `update_data.py` because it works correctly from `CLI`.

When I run the `cron` at the `python3` environment, I get the following:

```
*/2 * * * * /Users/BJay/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/python /Users/BJay/myGitHub/update_data.py
```

Here's an extract from the log of the cron output:

```
Subject: Cron <random@email.here> /Users/BJay/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/python /Users/BJay/myGitHub/update_data.py 
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=MrBee>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=MrBee>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/BJay>

===================================
0 of 0 repos updated successfully! 
===================================
```

Looking at the `X-Cron-Env`, could it be that `cron` is NOT using `anaconda` and it's using the default Python install instead?

How can I possibly remedy this situation?

If it helps, here's my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
import os; print(os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")); 

None
```

====== Here's the main part of the script I'm trying to run =====.

```
for repo in list_of_local_repos:
    repo_path = os.path.join(parent_path, repo)
    git_sequence = "cd {0} && git add . && git commit -m 'updated' && git push origin master".format(repo_path)
    if os.system(git_sequence) == 0:
         repos_updated += 1

repos_updated
```

This script works well when run in [ipython notebook. Here's the notebook.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/RichardAfolabi/Sandbox-for-stuffs/blob/master/Batch%20update%20GitHub%20repositories.ipynb) However, when run for the CLI using `python filename.py`, `os.system()` here always return `256` so `repos_updated` is never incremented.

Comment: I don't see where you're actually calling `os.system()`, and your last demonstration of `PYTHONPATH` doesn't show output.

Comment: I've added requested additional information to the question.